# How to view a dash app created on a Ubuntu server without GUI (a VM instance in gcp)

Tags: html, r, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, plotly-dash

I have an R script that uses Plotly Dash to create a web page. I am running the script on a VM instance in GCP which is a Ubuntu server without GUI. When the script is executed, it says,

start 127.0.0.1:8050

My question is how to access this web page on a browser from anywhere. Since the VM doesnt have a gui/browser I cannot even test my web page..

Anyone could explain what I am missing here or any way to deploy my web page and access from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure how your application works, but that ending line shows that the server is running on localhost and on which port is it serving. So you may want to access from an external browser with the instance's ip address: like `http:// xx.xxx.xx.xx:8050` and let's see if it works. Otherwise you may need to set up a [Remote Desktop Setup through Chrome](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine) to enable a GUI interface on the VM.

Also remember to make sure that traffic is allowed on that port 8050 checking /creating the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. You need to change the IP address on which the dash server is running to the internal IP address of your gcp VM instance. It usually starts with 10.xxx.x.x. You can find this internal address in the 'IP address' tab in the VPC networks section on the google cloud console. So do this:

`app.run_server(host='10.xxx.x.x', port='8050')`

Open a browser and browse to `http://externalip:8050`. Make sure you have your firewall rules set up correctly.
You should now be able to see the dash app.